# command \equal{#1}{} produces error if compactitem is in argument

Tags: errors, conditionals, itemize

I want to check if a variable is empty or not in a custom command.
This works well, as long as it contains "normal text" but as soon as there is an itemize environment, I get an error message:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{ifthen, paralist}

\begin{document}

\begin{compactitem}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\end{compactitem}

\newcommand{\equalsNothing}[1]{
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{true}{false}
}

\equalsNothing{}
\equalsNothing{1}

\equalsNothing{ 
\begin{compactitem}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\end{compactitem}
}

\end{document}
```

How can I change the \equalsNothing-command, so that it correctly works also with that itemize-content?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The arguments of `\equal` are *fully expanded* and this of course causes problems with fragile commands, such as `\begin`.

Say

```
\newcommand{\equalsNothing}[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\unexpanded{#1}}{}}{true}{false}%
}
```

In this way you look exactly whether there's something in the argument of `\equalsNothing`.

Don't forget to mask unwanted spaces with `%`. I'd also recommend to use **xifthen** instead of **ifthen**. For example, **xifthen** provides the test `\isempty` that *doesn't* expand its argument:

```
\newcommand{\equalsNothing}[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{true}{false}%
}
```